# Connecting couchdb container from another container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, couchdb, dockerfile

I'm trying to connect to my couchdb container from nodejs app which is running in another container. My docker-compose file is like this;

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    couchdb:
        image: couchdb
        container_name: my-db
        ports:
            - 5984:5984
        environment:
            COUCHDB_USER: admin
            COUCHDB_PASSWORD: password
    api:
       image: my-api
       container_name: my-api
       build: .
       command: npm run dev
       ports:
           - 8080:8080
       depends_on:
           - couchdb
       links:
           - couchdb
```

But I always get an error which says;

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:5984
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
```

I saw this post mentioning the same issue;
[how to map database from couchdb container to another containers webapp in same docker-compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484726/how-to-map-database-from-couchdb-container-to-another-containers-webapp-in-same)

When I try that, I'm getting the same error.
New docker compose file;

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    couchdb:
        image: couchdb
    container_name: my-db
    ports:
        - 5984:5984
    environment:
        COUCHDB_USER: admin
        COUCHDB_PASSWORD: password
api:
    image: my-api
    container_name: my-api
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
        - couchdb
    links:
        - couchdb
    environment:
        DB_URL: http://admin:password@couchdb:5984
```

Still the same error..

I'm trying to connect the couchdb container with its service name ('couchdb') in nodejs side. I also checked if the containers are on the same network. Both are on a network named 'my_default' using bridge driver.

When I try to connect to db from local running nodejs app, there is no problem.

Is there anything that I forgot?

Comment: You can always run a bash in your api container and try to debug the issue with curl

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the problem. Api sevice tries to connect to db while couchdb service is not ready. I wrote a docker-entrypoint.sh to make the api service wait for the couchdb service to be ready. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the port for the connection:

```
DB_URL: http://admin:password@couchdb:5984
```

Comment: Actually, it is a copy-paste error, sorry. It was included and there was the same error. I corrected it in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

To add to your finding that couchdb had been started *but was not ready*, the Docker article [Control startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) lists a few ways to handle that situation, including tools like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize), or a script to poll for the state of the dependency.